# converting lists to strings and integers in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary where I want to convert 'protein accession' values from lists into simple strings. Also, I want to convert lists of strings into lists of integers for example in 'sequence length', 'start location', 'stop location'.

`'protein accession': ['A0A0H3LJT0_e']` into `'protein accession': 'A0A0H3LJT0_e'`

`'sequence length': ['102']` into `'sequence length': [102]`

and so on

Here is the sample of my dictionary:

```py
{
    "A0A0H3LJT0_e": {
        "protein accession": ["A0A0H3LJT0_e"],
        "sequence length": ["102"],
        "analysis": ["SMART"],
        "signature accession": ["SM00886"],
        "signature description": ["Dabb_2"],
        "start location": ["4"],
        "stop location": ["98"],
        "e-value": ["1.5E-22"],
        "interpro accession": ["IPR013097"],
        "interpro description": ["Stress responsive alpha-beta barrel"],
        "nunique": [2],
        "domain_count": [1],
    }
}
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask].
It also wouldn't hurt to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4996248).

Comment: Iterate over `.values()` and change `'protein accession'` value of each item. It's 2 lines of code.

Comment: The value associated with 'protein accession' is a list of string(s). In your sample data that list only has one element. How would you want to convert the list if there is more than 1 element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also want to convert the string representation of a floating point number then you could do this (which also allows for list values with more than one element:

```
sample = {
    "A0A0H3LJT0_e": {
        "protein accession": ["A0A0H3LJT0_e"],
        "sequence length": ["102"],
        "analysis": ["SMART"],
        "signature accession": ["SM00886"],
        "signature description": ["Dabb_2"],
        "start location": ["4"],
        "stop location": ["98"],
        "e-value": ["1.5E-22"],
        "interpro accession": ["IPR013097"],
        "interpro description": ["Stress responsive alpha-beta barrel"],
        "nunique": [2],
        "domain_count": [1]
    }
}

for sd in sample.values():
    if isinstance(sd, dict):
        for k, v in sd.items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                try:
                    sd[k] = list(map(int, v))
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        sd[k] = list(map(float, v))
                    except ValueError:
                        sd[k] = ', '.join(map(str, v))

print(sd)
```

**Output:**

```
{'protein accession': 'A0A0H3LJT0_e', 'sequence length': [102], 'analysis': 'SMART', 'signature accession': 'SM00886', 'signature description': 'Dabb_2', 'start location': [4], 'stop location': [98], 'e-value': [1.5e-22], 'interpro accession': 'IPR013097', 'interpro description': 'Stress responsive alpha-beta barrel', 'nunique': [2], 'domain_count': [1]}
```

**Note:**

Unless every value in a list can be converted to either int or float, the values will be converted into a single string where each element is separated from the other by ', '

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the replace values accordingly.

`d` is the input dictionary here.

```
In [1]: data = d['C4QY10_e']

In [2]: result = {}

In [3]: for k,v in data.items():
  ...:     if str(v[0]).isdigit():
  ...:         result[k] = [int(v[0])]
  ...:     else:
  ...:         result[k] = v[0]
  ...: 

In [4]: result
Out[4]: 
{'protein accession': 'C4QY10_e',
 'sequence length': [1879],
 'analysis': 'Pfam',
 'signature accession': 'PF18314',
 'signature description': 'Fatty acid synthase type I helical domain',
 'start location': [328],
 'stop location': [528],
 'e-value': '4.7E-73',
 'interpro accession': 'IPR041550',
 'interpro description': 'Fatty acid synthase type I',
 'nunique': [1],
 'domain_count': [5]}
```

To iterate through the entire dictionary like this,

```
for val in d.values():
    for k,v in val.items():
        if str(v[0]).isdigit():
            result[k] = [int(v[0])]
        else:
            result[k] = v[0]
```

If you want to change the dictionary itself you can do this,

```
for main_k, main_val in d.items():
    for k,v in main_val.items():
        if str(v[0]).isdigit():
            d[main_k][k] = [int(v[0])]
        else:
            d[main_k][k] = v[0]
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. May I ask how to make this code iterate through keys from the entire dictionary? I was trying to do this on my own but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aurinko, as I suggested in [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74087031/10824407#comment130807965_74087031) comment, you can iterate only just values: `for data in your_dict.values():`

Comment: Btw, `for k, [v] in data.items():` will help to omit index.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new mapping-type object with nested container objects (e.g. `list`, `dict`, `set`, etc.), a `defaultdict` from the built-in `collections` library may be called for.

However, let's assume you are modifying the existing dictionary in place, thus preserving the `dict` type. We can use two explicit `for` loops over `dict.items()`:

```py
# assume input is stored to the variable, data
for name, details in data.items():  # Also possible to use for details in data.values():
    for attribute, values in details.items():
        # Use tuple unpacking to raise a ValueError
        # when no values or more than one value unexpectedly appears
        (value,) = values

        # Only consider strings with decimal values
        if isinstance(value, str) and value.isdecimal():
            # details is a reference to data[name]
            details[attribute] = int(value)
        else:
            details[attribute] = value
```

Comment: who not `for attribute, (value,)`?

Comment: `for attribute, (value,)` is certainly preferable for brevity.
I opted for the more explicit approach to avoid introducing too many potentially unfamiliar concepts (i.e. `.items()` and tuple unpacking) at once.